# getting certain bytes from byte array in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, byte

I have a byte array containing bytes from a file([see my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991425/reading-bytes-in-a-file-in-vb-net))
now I want to get the second lot of 4 bytes from the array and convert them to an integer
something like `bytearray.get(4[start],4[length])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim result as Int32

result = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytearray, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function ByteArrayToInteger(ByRef ByteArray() As Byte, ByRef StartIndex As Integer, ByRef EndIndex As Integer) As Integer
    Dim bSubArray(0 To EndIndex - StartIndex) As Byte
    For i As Integer = StartIndex To EndIndex
        bSubArray(i - StartIndex) = ByteArray(i)
    Next
    Return BitConverter.ToInt32(bSubArray, 0)
End Function
```

'calling it :

```
Dim b() As Byte = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
Dim x As Integer = ByteArrayToInteger(b, 0, 3)
```

Comment: note that to convert bytes to an integer you need at least 4 bytes to do the conversion or an exception will be thrown

Comment: I know, but I think this answer is too complicated the above one seems simple. Is this way a better way to do it?

Comment: its more flexible with this way